# ruby 1.9, force_encoding, but check

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

I have a string I have read from some kind of input.

To the best of my knowledge, it is UTF8.  Okay:

```
string.force_encoding("utf8")
```

But if this string has bytes in it that are not in fact legal UTF8, I want to know now and take action.

Ordinarily, will force_encoding("utf8") raise if it encounters such bytes? I *believe* it will not.

If I was doing an [#encode](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-encode) I could choose from the handy options with what to do with characters that are invalid in the source encoding (or destination encoding).

But I'm not doing an #encode, I'm doing a #force_encoding. It has no such options.

Would it make sense to

```
string.force_encoding("utf8").encode("utf8")
```

to get an exception right away? Normally encoding *from* utf8 *to* utf8 doesn't make any sense. But maybe this is the way to get it to raise right away if there's invalid bytes? Or use the `:replace` option etc to do something different with invalid bytes?

But no, can't seem to make that work either.

Anyone know?

```
1.9.3-p0 :032 > a = "bad: \xc3\x28 okay".force_encoding("utf-8")
=> "bad: \xC3( okay"
1.9.3-p0 :033 > a.valid_encoding?
=> false
```

Okay, but how do I find and eliminate those bad bytes?  Oddly, this does NOT raise:

```
1.9.3-p0 :035 > a.encode("utf-8")
 => "bad: \xC3( okay"
```

If I was converting to a different encoding, it would!

```
1.9.3-p0 :039 > a.encode("ISO-8859-1")
Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError: "\xC3" followed by "(" on UTF-8
```

Or if I told it to, it'd replace it with a "?" =>

```
1.9.3-p0 :040 > a.encode("ISO-8859-1", :invalid => :replace)
=> "bad: ?( okay"
```

So ruby's got the smarts to know what are bad bytes in utf-8, and to replace em with something else -- when converting to a different encoding. But I don't *want* to convert to a different encoding, i want to stay utf8 -- but I might want to raise if there's an invalid byte in there, or I might want to replace invalid bytes with replacement chars.

Isn't there some way to get ruby to do this?

**update** I believe this has finally been added to ruby in 2.1, with String#scrub present in the 2.1 preview release to do this. So look for that!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(update: see https://github.com/jrochkind/scrub_rb)

So I coded up a solution to what I needed here: https://github.com/jrochkind/ensure_valid_encoding/blob/master/lib/ensure_valid_encoding.rb

But only much more recently did I realize this actually IS built into the stdlib, you just need to, somewhat counter-intuitively, pass 'binary' as the "source encoding":

```
a = "bad: \xc3\x28 okay".force_encoding("utf-8")
a.encode("utf-8", "binary", :undef => :replace)
=> "bad: �( okay"
```

Yep, that's exactly what I wanted. So turns out this IS built into 1.9 stdlib, it's just undocumented and few people know it (or maybe few people that speak English know it?). Although I saw these arguments used this way on a blog somewhere, so someone else knew it!

Comment: Using Ruby 1.9.3-p484, this erroneously flagged a \xc0 byte in an iso-8859-1 file as an improper encoding.  I've found that, for my few test cases, `encode('binary', :undef => :replace)` seems to work: the iso-8859-1 passes, but a UTF-8 file with an improper sequence is caught.

Comment: See [this new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21686992/238886) for code that does not suffer from the issue I mentioned above.

Answer (score 6):

In ruby 2.1, the stdlib finally supports this with `scrub`.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-scrub

Answer (score 4):

make sure that your scriptfile itself is saved as UTF8 and try the following

```
# encoding: UTF-8
p [a = "bad: \xc3\x28 okay", a.valid_encoding?]
p [a.force_encoding("utf-8"), a.valid_encoding?]
p [a.encode!("ISO-8859-1", :invalid => :replace), a.valid_encoding?]
```

This gives on my windows7 system the following

```
["bad: \xC3( okay", false]
["bad: \xC3( okay", false]
["bad: ?( okay", true]
```

So your bad char is replaced, you can do it right away as follows

```
a = "bad: \xc3\x28 okay".encode!("ISO-8859-1", :invalid => :replace)
=> "bad: ?( okay"
```

EDIT: here a solution that works on any arbitrary encoding, the first encodes only the bad chars, the second just replaces by a ?

```
def validate_encoding(str)
  str.chars.collect do |c| 
    (c.valid_encoding?) ? c:c.encode!(Encoding.locale_charmap, :invalid => :replace)
  end.join 
end

def validate_encoding2(str)
  str.chars.collect do |c| 
    (c.valid_encoding?) ? c:'?'
  end.join 
end

a = "bad: \xc3\x28 okay"

puts validate_encoding(a)                  #=>bad: ?( okay
puts validate_encoding(a).valid_encoding?  #=>true


puts validate_encoding2(a)                  #=>bad: ?( okay
puts validate_encoding2(a).valid_encoding?  #=>true
```

Comment: I don't want to change encodings to ISO-8859-1. I want to leave it in the original encoding. Now you'll say "okay, then transcode to 8859 1 and then back again."  I want a solution that will work on any arbitrary encoding; you can't neccesarily transcode to 8859 and back without loss for any arbitrary encoding.

Comment: Thanks. I had independently arrived at something similar, but can you explain what this does: `c.encode!(Encoding.locale_charmap, :invalid => :replace)`?  Is that a transcode? I do not want to transcode (change the encoding) of the string, regardless of what encoding it starts out in and what my default locale encoding is. But I think I've already arrived at where you'll end up taking this into account too, see my self-answer on this question.

Comment: i don't change the encoding since it's the same as the encoding of the input string, anyway, you have your solution, that's what counts

Answer (score 3):

To check that a string has no invalid sequences, try to convert it to the *binary* encoding:

```
# Returns true if the string has only valid sequences
def valid_encoding?(string)
  string.encode('binary', :undef => :replace)
  true
rescue Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError => e
  false
end

p valid_encoding?("\xc0".force_encoding('iso-8859-1'))    # true
p valid_encoding?("\u1111")                               # true
p valid_encoding?("\xc0".force_encoding('utf-8'))         # false
```

This code replaces undefined characters, because we don't care if there are valid sequences that cannot be represented in binary.  We only care if there are invalid sequences.

A slight modification to this code returns the actual error, which has valuable information about the improper encoding:

```
# Returns the encoding error, or nil if there isn't one.

def encoding_error(string)
  string.encode('binary', :undef => :replace)
  nil
rescue Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError => e
  e.to_s
end

# Returns truthy if the string has only valid sequences

def valid_encoding?(string)
  !encoding_error(string)
end

puts encoding_error("\xc0".force_encoding('iso-8859-1'))    # nil
puts encoding_error("\u1111")                               # nil
puts encoding_error("\xc0".force_encoding('utf-8'))         # "\xC0" on UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

About the only thing I can think of is to transcode to something and back that won't damage the string in the round-trip:

```
string.force_encoding("UTF-8").encode("UTF-32LE").encode("UTF-8")
```

Seems rather wasteful, though.

Comment: ugh. In addition to being wasteful, it requires you being sure you know what encodings will be round-trippable without losing anything. I'd like a general purpose solution that will work on any arbitrary input encoding -- ruby knows how to do this with any encoding when actually trans-coding, why can't it do it for me? Annoying.

Comment: You can always round trip between any UTF's; Unicode is Unicode, no matter how you represent it.  It's only when you get out of Unicode that you might lose something in translation.

Comment: Huh?  You're already assuming that the input is UTF-8, which means you're already assuming Unicode.  I don't understand that objection.

Comment: I am writing library code, where I need to be able to "check and repair encoding validity" for any arbitrary character encoding. In this case, it was UTF-8, but it needs to be a library function that can deal with any arbitrary ruby 1.9 encoding as an input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's a really lame pure ruby way to do it I figured out myself. It probably performs for crap. what the heck, ruby? Not selecting my own answer for now, hoping someone else will show up and give us something better.

```
 # Pass in a string, will raise an Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError
 # if it contains an invalid byte for it's encoding; otherwise
 # returns an equivalent string.
 #
 # OR, like String#encode, pass in option `:invalid => :replace`
 # to replace invalid bytes with a replacement string in the
 # returned string.  Pass in the
 # char you'd like with option `:replace`, or will, like String#encode
 # use the unicode replacement char if it thinks it's a unicode encoding,
 # else ascii '?'.
 #
 # in any case, method will raise, or return a new string
 # that is #valid_encoding?
 def validate_encoding(str, options = {})
   str.chars.collect do |c|
     if c.valid_encoding?
       c
     else
       unless options[:invalid] == :replace
         # it ought to be filled out with all the metadata
         # this exception usually has, but what a pain!
         raise  Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError.new
       else
         options[:replace] || (
          # surely there's a better way to tell if
          # an encoding is a 'Unicode encoding form'
          # than this? What's wrong with you ruby 1.9?
          str.encoding.name.start_with?('UTF') ?
             "\uFFFD" :
             "?" )
       end
     end 
   end.join
 end
```

More ranting at http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/checkingfixing-bad-bytes-in-ruby-1-9-char-encoding/

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this for a "real-life" use case - for example for parsing different strings entered by users, and not just for the sake of being able to "decode" a totally random file which could be made of as many encodings as you wish, then I guess you could at least assume that all charcters for each string have the same encoding.

Then, in this case, what would you think about this?

```
strings = [ "UTF-8 string with some utf8 chars \xC3\xB2 \xC3\x93", 
             "ISO-8859-1 string with some iso-8859-1 chars \xE0 \xE8", "..." ]

strings.each { |s| 
    s.force_encoding "utf-8"
    if s.valid_encoding?
        next
    else
        while s.valid_encoding? == false 
                    s.force_encoding "ISO-8859-1"
                    s.force_encoding "..."
                end
        s.encode!("utf-8")
    end
}
```

I am not a Ruby "pro" in any way, so please forgive if my solution is wrong or even a bit naive..

I just try to give back what I can, and this is what I've come to, while I was (I still am) working on this little parser for arbitrarily encoded strings, which I am doing for a study-project.

While I'm posting this, I must admit that I've not even fully tested it.. I.. just got a couple of "positive" results, but I felt so excited of possibly having found what I was struggling to find (and for all the time I spent reading about this on SO..) that I just felt the need to share it as quick as possible, hoping that it could help save some time to anyone who has been looking for this for as long as I've been... .. if it works as expected :)

Comment: Here's what I ended up doing: https://github.com/jrochkind/ensure_valid_encoding/blob/master/lib/ensure_valid_encoding.rb

The key thing is that I know what the string is _supposed_ to be encoded as, but it may have bad bytes in it. Your solution is more trying to guess what the encoding 'really' is, which is a different problem.

Comment: To recap: 1) you either have bad encoded characters or data corruption, (from rationale at your github you assume that both things could be the problem cause), 2) you seem not to care about wrong encoding,because you only want to keep valid utf-8 chars(you don't to check if bad data is valid with different encoding) - People adviced to convert to another encoding as a mean to check for non valid bytes, but then you are afraid of possibly loosing some data. What's the point in that if you are not verifying the validity of the assumed encoding in the first place?(so possbly loosing data anyway?)

Comment: Thanks for answering by trying to convince me it's stupid to do what I need to do, but apparently many others disagree since ruby added it to the stdlib with String#scrub in ruby 2.1!  In fact, I understand what I'm doing, and there are many cases where it makes sense to do this (have you tried checking to see what vim, or your other favorite editor, does in this case?), but the point of this ticket was not to convince you of that fact.

Comment: #scrub is for when you are SURE of a string encoding, otherwise you will be loosing data. You said in the first comment above that you "know what the string is _SUPPOSED_ to be encoded as". This, in English, does not mean that you are 100% SURE about the encoding, but it is only SUPPOSED to be so. So don't complain. If you didn't mean that, then you could have simply said from the beginning that you were SURE about the encoding and that you only wanted to strip off bad bytes. And by the way, before #scrub, you had to manually go through different encodings to do that. Which is what I advised.

Comment: If there were bad bytes in it, then you obviously were wrong about being 100% sure about the encoding!  It was, by definition, not that encoding. Before scrub was in the stdlib, you had to figure out how to implement scrub yourself in pure ruby, which is what I ended up doing -- and not by going through encodings one by one, which was not what I was looking for-- what scrub does is what i was looking for.  Do you in general have much success on stackoverflow in trying to tell people their requirements are stupid and they are stupid and they shoudln't be asking the question they are asking?

Comment: Hey man cut the drama. I never called you stupid or did that with your requirements. I did not even imply that. I just gave my advice on how to solve a problem. I think you created a lot of confusion with the way you were expressing what you needed. Transcoding was a way to get rid of invalid encoding, but you didn't like it, because you wanted a solution where you could NOT assume UTF-8, as in your comments to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10201498/988591 but now you praise #scrub which only works on UTF-8. Make up your mind instead of throwing your frustration at who tried to help.

Comment: Okay, yeah, this gets tiresome. I will point out however that it is not true that MRI 2.1 scrub only works on UTF-8; it does work on any encoding. You can call it on a string with any encoding at all, it will remove (or replace) illegal bytes for that encoding. In fact, scrub meets my requirements perfectly, it's exactly what I needed. I apologize if I stated my requirements unclearly, that's what I meant when I wrote: "find and eliminate those bad bytes"--pre-scrub, I needed a pure ruby implementation of scrub, which does not 'go through different encodings'. And i found one.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to provoke an exception seems to be:

untrusted_string.match /./

Comment: If you just want an exception for invalid strings, you can simply do: `raise Exception.new unless string.valid_encoding?`  It's replacing the bad bytes with replacement chars that is more challenging.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 common situations and how to deal with them in **Ruby 2.1+**. I know, the question refers to Ruby v1.9, but maybe this is helpful for others finding this question via Google.

## Situation 1

**You have an UTF-8 string with possibly a few invalid bytes**
Remove the invalid bytes:

```rb
str = "Partly valid\xE4 UTF-8 encoding: äöüß"

str.scrub('')
 # => "Partly valid UTF-8 encoding: äöüß"
```

## Situation 2

**You have a string that could be in either UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 encoding**
Check which encoding it is and convert to UTF-8 (if necessary):

```rb
str = "String in ISO-8859-1 encoding: \xE4\xF6\xFC\xDF"

unless str.valid_encoding?
  str.encode!( 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '?' )
end #unless
 # => "String in ISO-8859-1 encoding: äöüß"
```

**Notes**

- The above code snippets assume that Ruby encodes all your strings in `UTF-8` by default. Even though, this is almost always the case, you can make sure of this by starting your scripts with `# encoding: UTF-8`.
- If invalid, it is programmatically possible to detect most multi-byte encodings like `UTF-8` (in Ruby, see: `#valid_encoding?`). However, it is NOT (easily) possible to programmatically detect invalidity of single-byte-encodings like `ISO-8859-1`. Thus the above code snippet does not work the other way around, i.e. detecting if a String is valid `ISO-8859-1` encoding.
- Even though `UTF-8` has become increasingly popular as the default encoding in the web, `ISO-8859-1` and other `Latin1` flavors are still very popular in the Western countries, especially in North America. Be aware that there a several single-byte encodings out there that are very similar, but slightly vary from ISO-8859-1. Examples: `CP1252` (a.k.a. `Windows-1252`), `ISO-8859-15`

Comment: I would not pass a parameter to scrub though, I'd _want_ the bad bytes showing up as unicode replacement char (�), not being erased entirely. I think the default is the correct appropriate default behavior.

Comment: @jrochkind: I agree that for different applications you want to have different behavior. If a human will look at the converted string(s), then most likely you want to replace bad bytes by the default replacement character (�). However, there are also other situations. To give an example: Where I come from, we work with gigabytes of data streams with unreliable encodings. We want to filter only certain informations. To work properly, we need valid UTF-8 strings, but we don't care for bad bytes. In scenarios like this, I recommend removing bad bytes.

Comment: I'm sure there are cases that's appropriate, but they are special purpose. No matter how many gigabytes of data, I don't think I'd ever want an improperly encoded Macapá (a city in Brazil) turning into Macap (a place in Indonesia) instead of Macap�.  As the general default suggestion without knowing someone's special use case, the default of the routine using the unicode replacement char is appropriate -- those unicode folks knew what they were doing.