# Non destructive force_encoding?

Tags: ruby, encoding

Is there a version from the method `force_encoding` that don't modify the caller object?

So, the current force_encoding works like this:

```
> a
 => "Ü" 
> a.force_encoding("BINARY")
 => "\xC3\x9C" 
> a
 => "\xC3\x9C"
```

I would like the result to be like this:

```
> a
 => "Ü" 
> a.force_encoding_non_destructive("BINARY")
 => "\xC3\x9C" 
> a
 => "Ü"
```

Note that I fully understand that `a.force_encoding("UTF-16LE").force_encoding("UTF-8")` yelds the same result (assuming that `a` was previously UTF-8, of course) and the bytes in string is not modified. However, the string state is modified, and thus this method is destructive. for example:

```
a="a"
a.freeze
a.force_encoding("BINARY")
# raises error
```

Comment: try the above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200544/ruby-1-9-force-encoding-but-check

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what `force_encoding` actually does in your example. It's not modifying your string's content in any way. Rather, it is changing a property of the string -- the one which controls how it is presented to you.

Comment: @Denis I belive you are wrong. Try this in your console: `a = "a" ; b = "b" ; a + b`. Afterwards, try this: `a = "a" ; b = "b" ; a + b ; a.force_encoding("UTF-16LE"); a + b`. If the same statement generates different output after calling a method in one of the objects implicates in that method modified the object state.

Comment: Hold. Changing to `UTF-16LT` is not the same as changing to binary (which you used in your example). :-) Binary is just that... a stream of bytes. `UTF-8` and `UTF-16` encode the same character differently, and modify the string accordingly (when possible). In contrast and to the best of my knowledge, forcing a string to binary yields the exact same string.

Comment: @Denis while in practice it behaves Binary behaves very likely UTF-8, the simple fact that `a.encoding` returns an different value after a `force_encoding` it means that the object was changed. A easier way to prove is `a="a"; a.freeze; a.force_encoding("BINARY")` -> raises an error

Comment: Yes, the object's encoding property has changed. But not the string itself, when you switch to an encoding to binary and back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`force_encoding` is non-destructive in terms of not changing the receiver's bytes. It just changes how the bytes are interpreted, i.e. it changes the string's *characters*:

```
a = "Ü"
a.bytes.to_a               #=> [195, 156]
a.chars.to_a               #=> ["Ü"]

a.force_encoding("BINARY")
a.bytes.to_a               #=> [195, 156]
a.chars.to_a               #=> ["\xC3", "\x9C"]
```

The encoding is stored within the string instance. To get a copy in "binary" encoding use:

```
a.dup.force_encoding("BINARY")
```

Comment: So how do explain this: `a="a"; a.freeze; a.force_encoding("BINARY")`? I'll edit my question to cover this too, since you are not the first telling this.

Comment: I said *"not changing the receiver's bytes"*. The string's encoding does change. I've updated my answer.

Comment: a="Ü"; b="Ü"; a.force_encoding("BINARY"); a.bytes.to_a == b.bytes.to_a => true

Comment: Read my comment in the answer above - I suggest you to add a simple method implementation using dup... since that is what the question asks :-)

Answer (score 2):

I deeply apologize for another short answer. Obviously, `#force_encoding` modifies the string attribute, but I would not go so far as calling it destructive. You can always reverse the change. If you want to have your cake, and eat it, `#dup` it.

Comment: Actually this time the answer have more content than already told in the comments or in a simple googling, because this works: `a.freeze.dup.force_encoding("BINARY")`, so an object loses the freeze when duplicated. If there is no standard method to do this, so maybe the best way is to dup it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
a = "Ü"
b = ::String.new a, :encoding => "binary"
```

I like it more than `dup`.