# Ruby On Rails 3.2 Accepting parameters encoded in other than UTF-8 encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, utf-8

I'm integrating outsourced service (will call it service further on) into rails 3.2.16 application.

The does a POST request (will call it request) to our application.

The request predefined request parameters are you used to calculate verification string. The verification string generator takes values and it lengths of parameters.

the problem is that the service posts a request encoded in Windows-1257 encoding, but RoR assumes ([i mean it](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=assume)) that parameters are encoded in UTF-8 which is true to all other our application actions except this only one.

let's say:

```
2.1.0 :027 > 'Petračiauskas'.encode('Windows-1257') 
=> "Petra\xE8iauskas" 
params['first_param'] = "Petra\xE8iauskas" # i receive parameter like that
2.1.0 :030 > 'Petračiauskas'.encode('Windows-1257').encoding 
=> #<Encoding:Windows-1257> 
2.1.0 :031 > "Petra\xE8iauskas".length
=> 13 
2.1.0 :047 > 'Petračiauskas'.length
=> 13 
2.1.0 :048 > 'Petračiauskas' == "Petra\xE8iauskas"
=> false
```

the problem is that when i receive a POST request to my controller action from the service rails treats it as it's in UTF-8.

To sum up:

1. I'm not in control of the post parameters or its encoding
2. I have to accept it and convert it to UTF-8

I'm stuck on this for more that half of day, did read quite a bit and tried this and that including ([ForceParamsEncoding](https://coderwall.com/p/z5742a)) what this posts suggest with the modification to Rails 3 (lib => config/initializers/) without no luck

I would really appreciate any help.

Will create demo app if this is not enough.

Thanks

BTW: i believe that this theme could use a tag 'Windows-1257' and 'parameters-encoding', but i don't have enough rep for that.

---

update
[rails 3.2 branch @ github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/parameters.rb)
http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActionDispatch/Http/Parameters/encode_params

> encode_params(params) private
>
> TODO: Validate that the characters are UTF-8. If they aren’t, you’ll get a weird error
>   down the road, but our form handling should really prevent that from happening

Comment: ` problem is that the service posts a request encoded in Windows-1257` cat you access to serivce to force it to use utf-8?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200544/ruby-1-9-force-encoding-but-check

Comment: try to set `Encoding.default_internal = 'Windows-1257'; Encoding.default_external = 'Windows-1257'` into **config/boot.rb**

Comment: Brad Werth: no it does not help, there's a difference between single and double quotes, and please be more specific, which part of the whole tread helps?

Comment: And i should not set such thing as external/internal encoding to the different one than UTF-8. It's a single action on pretty large scale application, do you really understand what are you suggestion like?

Comment: Here's a class extension you might find useful: https://gist.github.com/Malet/7942995 - just do `'Petračiauskas'.to_utf8`

Comment: in the task description i've wrote: 'The request predefined request parameters are you used to calculate verification string. The verification string generator takes values and it lengths of parameters.'